# JApplet in JSP class not found

Tags: jsp, applet

I realsie that similar questions have been answered here about this problem but im really struggling here as this is the first Japplet i have had to make.

Basically im getting a class not found exception when trying to embed my test Japplet:

```
public class JTwainUI extends JApplet{
public void init ()
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    frame.setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 0));

    panel = new JPanel();
    button = new JButton("upload from scanner");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            initScan();
        }
    });
    panel.add(button);

    frame.add(panel);
    this.add(frame);
    this.repaint();
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

in myjsp page:

```
<jsp:plugin 
type="applet"  
code="JTwainUI.class"
    codebase="jTwain.JTwainUI"
    width="600" height="500">
</jsp:plugin>
```

where my java class is in: WEB-INF\classes\jTwain

I really dont understand whats going on, how can the class not be found p.s. ive tried doing the code base as WEB-INF.classes.jTwain etc and my java version should be fine because the applets on suns website work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The /WEB-INF/classes dir is not visible from the client explorer java environment (which is where the applet is run), so when it's trying to load your class, it can't found it.

Maybe [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253786/run-applet-in-web-application/4253935#4253935) to a (quite) similar question can help you.

**Edit:** suposing you have saved your class in an accesible dir (in a folder called /applet), your code should look something like this:

```
<jsp:plugin 
type="applet"  
code="jTwain.JTwainUI"
    codebase="/YourApplicationContext/applet"
    width="600" height="500">
</jsp:plugin>
```

Comment: So in the main folder which contains WEB-INF/META-INF folder i made a folder called applet and in there i transferred the JTwainUI.class and also created a jar file of it and put it there aswell; changed my codebase to: codebase="/MyWebApp/applet" and still nothing. (This is what i interpreted from your link)

Comment: It's one of this. Not both. And, anyway, you'll need to keep the package structure (under the applet folder, or inside the JAR file)

Comment: ok so i changed the applet folder to have jTwain/JTwainUI.class instead of just JTwainUI.class without its package, removed the jar and still no go

Comment: @slex: you have to check the value at the code attribute too.

Comment: still nothing; ive got this feeling that its not to do with the code. What are other things that could make this happen?

Comment: What does the browser report when you try a direct fetch with this address in the address bar? - (http://localhost:8080/YourApplicationContext/applet/jTwain/JTwainUI.class)  Change local host for the site name, if needed.  As an aside, until you understand the HTML produced by JSP, you should be testing/debugging this using pure HTML.  The Java Console should also be configured to pop open for every applet launch.  The paucity of information you are supplying suggests you are unaware of it.

Comment: Basically what tomas said worked in regards to displaying the app in the web page. I now have a problem with certificates and "AccessControlException: access denied" but i will start a new question. Thank You.