# how to play a java game in a blog

Tags: java, blogs

I have created a game in java. I want to place that game in my blog. How to do this?  thanks in advance.

Comment: um... i hope you mean java applet...

Comment: Compress all of your Java code files into an archive (like a `.zip` or `.rar` file), and then provide a link to download those files on your blog.

Comment: might not need to be an applet, could be [Java Webstart](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136112.html), question is pretty vague though.

Comment: @cody: i am asking to play that game in that blog.. like the facebook games.. whether it is possible or not.

Comment: Totally depends on the blog software then - you can do it with HTML, but that doesn't mean your blog publishing software has exposed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll probably want to take a look at [Deploying an Applet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html) and [Deploying With the Applet Tag](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/html.html). Since you're using Blogger this page might help you: [Adding Applet code into the blogger post](http://codingfreak.blogspot.com/2009/02/blogger-adding-applet-code-into-blogger.html).

Here's a small [working example](http://whitefang34.com/ImageIconApplet.html) on an applet if that helps. The HTML for that page is simply:

```
<applet width="200" height="200" archive="ImageIconApplet.jar"
        code="com.whitefang34.ImageIconApplet" />
```

The applet source code is:

```
public class ImageIconApplet extends JApplet {
    public void init() {
        URL url = getClass().getResource("/images/WhiteFang34.jpg");
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(icon, JLabel.CENTER);
        add(label);
    }
}
```

And the [packaged jar](http://whitefang34.com/ImageIconApplet.jar) for the applet contains:

```
/com/whitefang34/ImageIconApplet.class
/images/WhiteFang34.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure your blog supports/allows java applets, then follow a java applet tutorial and make sure your game fits in one.

http://www.echoecho.com/applets01.htm

Comment: I think I'd favour Java Webstart over applets these days, especially for games

Comment: i am using blogger.com. whether it will allow the java applets?

Answer (score 1):

Either offer a download for the game or rewrite your gui to use a java applet with it's init start stop and destroy methods

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JApplet.html

init is called once the browser loads your code.
start when you applet is being started
stop when it is being stopped
destroy when the browser unloads your code (mostly when you close the browser)

Answer (score 0):

For providing games online to play it is better to use Flash.
But as you want to use java (applet); to know how to integreate applet in your web-app see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253786/run-applet-in-web-application).