# How to run applet in web application

Tags: java, applet

I'm having the exact same problem stated in [run applet in web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253786/run-applet-in-web-application). It throws a `ClassNotFoundException` for my applet. I tried the solution from there but still no luck.

Here is my code for embedding Applet in html:

```
<body>
 <applet codebase="/DaaS/applet" archive="/DaaS/applet/firstApplet.jar" code="FirstApplet.class" width="300" height ="300"> </applet>
```

I've a folder `DaaS/applet` which contains firstApplet.jar and my `index.html` is in `Daas/Webcontent`.

Answer (score 1):

The URL in the `codebase` (and `archive`) attribute is relative to the current request URL (the one as you see in browser address bar), not to the disk file system in the server side. Imagine that you've the `index.html` page in some subfolder like so:

> http://localhost:8080/somecontext/index.html

The URL as you have in the `codebase` (and `archive`) attribute starts with a leading slash `/` which makes it relative to the domain root instead of the current folder. So the webbrowser will look for the archive and the JAR in the following URL

> http://localhost:8080/DaaS/applet/firstApplet.jar

This may not be correct per se. You need to make sure that the `codebase` (and `archive`) URL points to the right URL relative to the current request URL. Based on the information given so far, the `/DaaS` folder is basically in the same parent as `index.html`, so this should do:

```html
<applet codebase="DaaS/applet" archive="firstApplet.jar" ... />
```

*(note that I simplified the `archive` attribute, it will be resolved relative to `codebase` anyway)*

This way the browser will load the JAR from:

> http://localhost:8080/somecontext/DaaS/applet/firstApplet.jar

Comment: ` <applet codebase="DaaS/applet" archive="firstApplet.jar" 
  code="FirstApplet.class" width="300" height ="300">
 </applet>` tried but still no luck...